# #pragma mark similar in pycharm/python?

Tags: python, pycharm

Some times single py file has too many lines, goto the some specially method will be annoying.

`xcode` has a feature called [pragma mark](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-and-pragma-mark.html) . it can let developer locate some special operation methods. So pycharm has the same feature ?

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you mean `# region region_name ... # endregion` in order to be able to fold arbitrary blocks of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "bookmark".

> To make navigation around your code faster and more accurate, and help you not get lost or confused, there are bookmarks. With bookmarks you can mark the lines you need to remember and easily jump from one to another.
>   (https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/11/navigate-your-code-with-bookmarks/)

To add an "anonymous" (temporary) bookmark on the current line, press F11 (or select "Edit | Toggle Bookmark"); you can also add a one-key mnemonic to the bookmark, limited to `0-9` and `A-Z`, and add a description. See the web page above for a full description.